# How can I create a new gmail account for each run of my automation suite?

Tags: selenium, automation, gmail

I'm trying to test that our website registers a user who signs in with google, the tests run every build so I'm looking for a way to create a bunch of gmail accounts I can use every build.

I read that adding +1 to the email address will create a new account but when I enter my email+1@gmail.com the google pop up says "Couldn't find your Google account"

Is there another way I can create a random account for each test that doesn't include going through the UI?

Comment: adding +1 do not create a new Gmail account. +{number} creates a new name of your existing Gmail account and you will get the emails in the same email address.

Comment: You can try with yopmail, which does not require any account creation. Just use the email whereever you want in the code, and if you want to access go back to `yopmail.com` and just enter whatever the email that you entered. The emails will be wiped off after 24hrs, so you should be good. Let me know if you have any more questions.